# QWebPage cannot load full js staff

Tags: qtwebkit

I am using QWebPage to download some pages, including the js rendered content. But I found that sometimes, there is some js missing. The content which should be replaced by js rendering result remains empty.

I check the document for QWebPage, I guess I got the answer, “Finally, the loadFinished() signal is emitted when the page contents are loaded completely, independent of script execution or page rendering.”

But how can I wait until all script rendering finish.

Comment: I've run in to this before, I decided to give the JS a few seconds after loadFinished() before trying to do anything with the page.

Comment: Please check my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604365/checking-for-pending-calls  If there is an answer, it will probably help you too.